# Why are Haskell list comprehensions not executed in parallel?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, list-comprehension

I am doing Project Euler problem 21 for homework and I have this list comprehension:

```
amicableNumberSums = [ x+y | x<-[1..10000], y <-[1..10000], (amicable x y)]
```

This takes a very long time to execute (understandable as it tests 10000^2 pairs of numbers) and looking at my cpu usage it shows that only 1 core is being used.

As there are no side effects to the list comprehension there is no danger in multiple pairs of numbers being tested at the same time. Is there a way to make Haskell do this automatically or if not how could my code be modified to do this?

(Edit) Error when running print (amicableNumberSums `using` parList):

```
Couldn't match type `a0 -> Eval a0' with `[Int]'
Expected type: Strategy [Int]
  Actual type: Strategy a0 -> Strategy [a0]
In the second argument of `using', namely `parList'
In the first argument of `print', namely
  `(amicableNumberSums `using` parList)'
In the expression: print (amicableNumberSums `using` parList)
```

(Edit) Performance of the two suggested methods:

```
Ørjan Johansen's method: 218.79s elapsed parallel (4 cores + 4 hyperthreading)
                         279.37s elapsed sequential (single core)
bheklilr's method: 247.82s elapsed parallel (4 cores + 4 hyperthreading)
                   274.10s elapsed sequential (single core)
Original method: 278.69s elapsed
```

This is not as large a speed up as I was hoping for but I now have the correct answer to the problem and until I have learnt some more Haskell this is sufficient.

Comment: There are no side effects, but your list comprehension requires results to be in a specific order, so parallelizing the computation is not as trivially simple as you might imagine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@bheklilr's answer handles the general method of parallelizing strategies, but as I implied in the comment above, the way the original list comprehension is written forces all `amicable` tests to happen before a `parList`-based strategy on it can get to its elements and start evaluating them, so I don't think @bheklilr's code will quite work for this specific case.

Here's my suggestion for an improvement. You need to rewrite your list comprehension such that it divides the work into well-defined and independent chunks, e.g. by combining the `x` values in intermediate lists. For example it can be written equivalently as

```
concat [[ x+y | y <-[1..10000], (amicable x y)] | x <- [1..10000]]
```

Now you can put a parallel evaluation strategy in between the comprehension and the final `concat`:

```
concat ([[ x+y | y <-[1..10000], (amicable x y)] | x <- [1..10000]]
        `using` parList rdeepseq)
```

(I use `rdeepseq` here because the elements of the pre-concatted list are also lists, and we want to evaluate all their elements which are integers.)

Answer (score 20):

Here's a simple example:

```
simple = 1 : 1 : [a + b | a <- simple, b <- simple]
```

How would you parallelize this?  How would you generalize this to any list comprehension to decide if it can be parallelized?  What about any other list comprehension over a list that is infinite, sparking a new thread for each element would mean sparking infinite threads.  What if it's actually much faster to compute the list sequentially as the threading overhead is too large and slows down the computation?  What if only the first 10 elements of the list are needed?  It wouldn't be very good to compute the whole list greedily when a small fraction is required.

Instead, GHC chose to give the power to the programmer on when and how to parallelize a list computation.  Instead of doing things implicitly for you, you can choose how it's done using the `Control.Parallel.Strategies` module:

```
print $ amicableNumberSums `using` parList rdeepseq
```

Or calculating chunks of the list in parallel:

```
print $ amicableNumberSums `using` parListChunk 64 rdeepseq
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to use `seq` and co. to get your data into NF at the right times.

The API exposed by `Control.Parallel.Strategies` gives you the ability to define different ways of computing a pure data structure in parallel entirely separate from the data structure itself or even other algorithms.  This is in stark contrast to most other programming languages which force you to strongly couple your parallelism with your other algorithms, or even how the structure is constructed.  I'd highly recommend reading Simon Marlow's [Parallel and Concurrent Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929) (it's free online!), which does a much better job than I can at explaining how it works and how to use it.

Comment: Should the "print $ amicableNumberSums `using` parList" work without any other changes? When I try it I get the error seen in the edit to my question.

Comment: `parList` is not a `Strategy`, it is a *function* which makes a strategy for a list from a strategy for a single element. You would need to use `parList rseq` or similar. That said, I don't think `parList ...` will work directly with `amicleNumberSums` like this. That is because it requires the *spine* of the list to be evaluated before it can start evaluating elements in it, and the list comprehension is defined such that an element isn't put *in* the list until it's already checked that it's an amicable sum.

Comment: @Scytheon3 Sorry about that, I haven't used `parList` in a while and completely forgot that I needed `rdeepseq` or some other strategy on there to make it work.  Orjan Johansen is correct (and deserves a few upvotes) for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Underwhelmed with the results reported by the OP, I dug a little deeper. It turns out that using multiple cores not only requires the explicit parallelism code mentioned in other answers, but also specific **compilation** and **runtime** flags. Specifically for `ghc`, they are `-threaded` and `+RTS -N` respectively. With these settings I got a 5x speed improvement using 10 cores.

Complete runnable program:

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies ( parList, rdeepseq, using )

onefactor :: Int -> Int -> Int
onefactor x y
  | x `rem` y == 0 = y
  | otherwise = 0

auxsumfactors :: Int -> Int -> Int
auxsumfactors _ 1 = 1
auxsumfactors x y = onefactor x y + auxsumfactors x (y-1)

sumfactors :: Int -> Int
sumfactors 1 = 1
sumfactors x = auxsumfactors x (x-1)

amicable :: Int -> Int -> Bool
amicable i j = i == sumfactors j && j == sumfactors i


amicableNumberSums :: [Int]
amicableNumberSums = [ x+y | x<-[1..1000], y <-[1..10000], (amicable x y)]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $ amicableNumberSums
```

Note I reduced the `x` upper bound to 1000 for sanity sake. And the helper functions I just copied from [here](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Evxs/teaching/handouts/Haskell/answers/ans01.pdf).

Results (on my Apple M1 Max) are:

```
$ ghc parListComprehension.hs
$ time ./parListComprehension
[2,12,56,504,504,992]
./parListComprehension  1773.63s user 5.26s system 99% cpu 29:40.56 total
$ ghc -O2 parListComprehension.hs
$ time ./parListComprehension
[2,12,56,504,504,992]
./parListComprehension  31.97s user 0.07s system 98% cpu 32.411 total
```

so already, just setting `-O2` improves runtime by **55 times**! According to the [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#o-convenient-packages-of-optimisation-flags), `-O2` is the highest "convenient packages" of optimisations and means:

> Apply every non-dangerous optimisation, even if it means significantly longer compile times.

---

Now we add parallelism.

I was unable to detect any change in runtime behaviour using the example code in bheklilr's answer verbatim, so I've left those results out.

Instead, let's move straight to Ørjan Johansen's method by changing `amicableNumberSums` to:

```hs
amicableNumberSums = concat ([[ x+y | y <-[1..10000], (amicable x y)]
                              | x <- [1..1000]] `using` parList rdeepseq)
```

If I compile and run as before, the results **do not change** meaningfully, suggesting both that the change to `concat` did not introduce significant overhead, and by default the execution remains bound to a single core. To run on multiples cores, `ghc` needs some encouragement:

```bash
$ ghc -O2 -threaded parListComprehension.hs
$ time ./parListComprehension +RTS -N
[2,12,56,504,504,992]
./parListComprehension +RTS -N  57.20s user 0.20s system 940% cpu 6.103 total
```

so it seems there's quite a bit of overhead (nearly twice as much CPU time) but by throwing 10 cores at it we nonetheless get a 5x speed improvement.

The `-threaded` and `+RTS -N` flags go hand in hand - you can't have one without the other. The `+RTS` flag indicates that the flags that follow are for the "runtime system", and `-N <x>` specifies how many "simultaneous threads" are to be used. If `<x>` is not specified the runtime will choose itself "based on how many processors are in your machine". More info on these options in the [fine manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/using-concurrent.html#rts-options-for-smp-parallelism).